# How can docker service really scale in one machine?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-container

I can understand how it is helpful when scaling over multiple different machines.
But here we have just one single machine (or a node). However docker still supports scaling the service to run multiple tasks (each served by one container) like this:

```
docker service scale serviceName=num_of_replicas
```

Let's take an example of running a Web API. Really I don't see how scaling in this case can help. One machine hosting a web API can serve with its max power. Using multiple containers in it cannot help increase that maximum power. With the request handling pipeline of Web API, one server can handle multiple requests at the same time and independently as long as the server has enough resources (CPU, RAM). So we don't need multiple (unnecessary) tasks in this case with docker service scaling.

The only benefit I can see here is docker service scaling may provide a better isolation between tasks (containers) compared with serving all the requests by one same server (container).

Could you please let me know some other benefit of scaling docker service this way? Is there anything wrong with my assumption above?

Comment: Don't know about docker swarm, but with Kubernetes you could update an application with zero downtime. With multiple instances, one got updated after the others so users can switch on the remaining ones. To make this work, the application must support it. I'm sure that docker swarm offer similar features.

Answer (score 0):

> Using multiple containers in it cannot help increase that maximum power.

That really depends on the implementation. Some non efficient implementations may use only single process/thread/cpu and scaling helps with their performance.

Another benefit: scaling on the single node will help also with high availability. There is always small nonzero chance for non recoverable error, out of memory issue, ... which may stop single container. So there will be downtime, until orchestration scheduler restarts container.